# iOS: PushPlugin.m error: no visible @interface

Tags: ionic-framework

I am getting the following error while building on ios:

> PushPlugin.m error: no visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:'

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

1. cordova platform remove ios
2. cordova platform add ios@3.9.2

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue here.

Using Cordova 6.0.0 and updated to cordova-ios 4.0.1 on
Xcode 7.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Turns out I had multiple "PushPlugin" and one was not compatible with ios@4.1.0. So what I did was

1. ionic platform rm ios (remove ios@3.9.2)
2. ionic platform add ios@4.1.0
3. cordova plugin list (to see if you have multiple pushplugins)
4. cordova remove PushPlugin-name
5. ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="XXXXXX"